# Cypress Open UI not visible

Tags: testing, cypress

When I run the command npx cypress open
The cypress window is launched but the UI is not visible for some reason
I've tried npm install cypress@latest --save-dev, but it's still not working
Cypress Version:
Cypress package version: 10.3.1
Cypress binary version: 10.3.1
Electron version: 18.3.0
Bundled Node version:
16.13.2
Node Version:
v16.14.0

Comment: You can try running a test example like this: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-kitchensink

Answer (score 15):

Hover over the cypress icon on your task bar and you'll see the mini-window of cypress UI. Right click on that mini-window and click "maximize"

Comment: It's crazy. You saved my life

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. Just adding details in case it is the same issue as "Program Appears On The Task Bar But Not On The Screen"

The fix is to use old keyboard commands to resize the program window:

- Put your mouse over (do NOT click) the program in the Task Bar until the preview appears directly above it
- Right Click on the preview and select SIZE or MOVE
- Press the Down or Right arrow key on the keyboard have it resize to what should be its minimum size
- Press the ENTER key on your keyboard when it is moved
- You can then use the mouse to resize the window as you see fit

If none of these options work:

- Put your mouse over (do NOT click) the program in the Task Bar until the preview appears directly above it
- Right Click on the preview and select MAXIMIZE

If the program appears full screen, then it is running but is just not visible to you.  Click RESTORE and try both of the options above again.

Picked from this blog https://www.urtech.ca/2017/03/solved-program-appears-task-bar-not-screen/

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar issue. Here is the Fix:

I think you might have used Extended Display and probably have dragged the Cypress Runner on another screen, so if you have removed the extended screen and trying to open in you Laptop now, it will not open. Its a very weird issue on Cypress.
To Fix this, you have to connect you Screen(HDMI) again and then you might see the popup on that display. Drag again to you Laptop screen and then disconnect. It will work.